# Lualatex function producing trailing characters

Tags: luatex

This function was working in the production system and I'm not aware of changing anything (MikTeX did some package updates which may have had an effect).

A very much stripped down MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
    function underscore(s)                                      
        s = tostring(s+2080)      
        tex.print(s)                                           
    end                                                    
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Binl}[1]{\directlua{underscore([[#1]])}}% 

\begin{document}

Use M\Binl{1} or M\Binl{2}

\end{document}
```

I used to get M_1 and M_2 with proper subscripts, but now the correct unicode characters U+2081 and U+2082 are being generated but have acquired a trailing ".0" as can be seen in the output.  N.B. I've omitted prepending "\char\"" to s before passing the string back.

Output :

```
Use M2081.0 or M2082.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's due to the change from lua 5.2 to lua 5.3.

You can force the number to be an integer e.g. with `math.floor`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
    function underscore(s)
        s = tostring(math.floor(s+2080))
        tex.print(s)
    end
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Binl}[1]{\directlua{underscore([[#1]])}}%

\begin{document}

Use M\Binl{1} or M\Binl{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike Fischer.  That fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = tostring(math.floor(s+2080))
```

Comment: Thanks Red-Cloud.  Millisecs behind Ulrike.